# DNS have an answer that isn't supposed to exist

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi

I've set up my relay on my PC but I'm trying to create a relay on a raspberry pi that I can leave powered on at all times but when I start the daemon I get:

> [notice] Your DNS provider gave an answer for 'xxxx.invalid', which is not supposed to exist. Apparently they are highjacking DNS failures. Trying to correct for this. We've noticed 1 possibly bad address so far.
>      [notice] Your DNS provider has given 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' as an answer for 10 different invalid addresses. Apparently they are hijacking DNS failures. I'll try to correct for this by treating future occurrences of 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' as 'not found'

My torrc file:

```
ORPort 443
ExitPolicy Reject ":"
Nickname xxxx
RelayBandwidthRate 300KB
RelayBandwidtBurst 500KB
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
```

I do have another tor relay running, but I don't think that's the issue.

The ports are definitely open, so I'm not sure what the issue is and any guidance would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you choose another DNS server (like 8.8.8.8) and not only use the one from your provider?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem as you are not a exit node. Tor will check if your DNS server was hijacking DNS failures, through looking up random domain names and see if it always gets the same address (generally an error page), even if you are not an exit node. Also Tor will correct DNS hijackings itself, so nothing needs to be done.
Not about raspberry-pi either.

Comment: The issue is I've had the daemon running over night and the nickname still isn't showing on Globe o Atlas, but the relay I have set on my PC showed in about an hour.

Comment: Is there any traffic goes through your relay? And could you please post more detailed logs?